# How to add additional objects to an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am looking to learn how to add an object to array with multiple existing objects following the constructor function which I created.

```
//constructor function
function Bookdes(title, author, pages, current_page, available){
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.current_page = current_page;
    this.available = available;
}
//array of books
var bookarrays = [
    new Bookdes("Fast Cars", "John Burns", 205, 43, "true"),
    new Bookdes("Slow Cars", "Joe Fast", 70, 32, "false" ),
    new Bookdes("Big Cars", "Darla Jean", 234, 42, "true"),
    new Bookdes("Small Cars", "Dema Jones", 214, 34, "false"),
    new Bookdes("Cars", "Alex Best", 235, 41, "true")
];

//Add two more books
bookarrays.push("Gasoline Car", "Johnny Walker", 200, 31, "true");
bookarrays.push("Natural gas car", "James Dean", 150, 21, "true");
console.log(bookarrays);
```

thanks,

Comment: If you ever write `"true"` as a string, you should probably use `true` (the Boolean value).

Comment: `bookarrays.push( new Bookdes("Nice Cars", "Joe Mama", 72, 12, "false" ))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you don't call the constructor. The right call is:

```
bookarrays.push(new Bookdes("Gasoline Car", "Johnny Walker", 200, 31, "true"));
```

Comment: Oh so close, but no cigar! Thank you for the help!

Comment: How would I edit an existing element ---                                           //Change book to available or not available
Bookdes.prototype.checkout = function(avail){
 if(avail === "true")
  Bookdes.prototype.available = "true";
 else if(avail === "false")
  Bookdes.prototype.available = "false";
 else
  console.error("Entry not accepted please enter true or false");
};
console.log(bookarrays[2].checkout("true"));
console.log(bookarrays);